# How to finish the Dexter's Laboratory: Deesaster Strikes! GBA game?

Tags: dexter-deesaster-strikes

I was playing *[Dexter's Laboratory: Deesaster Strikes!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter%27s_Laboratory:_Deesaster_Strikes!)* and thought I had completed everything (I've just finished the house level), but obviously I'm missing something as I didn't get an ending. It just took me back to the hub. I searched the hub map to find if I missed something, so I can go back and complete it, but I didn't find anything. I don't want to go through each level as I know I've got 100% for most. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: By "dexters deesaster", I assume you mean [Dexter's Laboratory: Deesaster Strikes!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter%27s_Laboratory:_Deesaster_Strikes!)

Comment: Yes that's the one

Answer (score 1):

One needs to fix all 43 machines and capture all 124 small Dee Dees. From the start menu your game should show 100% complete. Assuming 100% completion then when Dexter is in the Hub walk him over to the left where the machine is that holds all the captured Dee Dees....and press the A button....a recombined DEE DEE walks out of the machine and the game goes to credits.